# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and samba 4

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, active-directory, samba

I am experiencing a very weird situation. When logged into my database server with a domain account (which is also a member of the local administrators group) the `sa` user is unable to connect to SQL Server Management Studio. However, logging in as a local admin account the `sa` user logs in successfully.

To make things more confusing... when logged into the Windows Server with a domain account (which is also a member of the local administrators group) SQL Server Management Studio will connect using Windows authentication.

A few notes:

1. While logged into the server with a domain account `sa` CAN connect via `sqlcmd`.
2. `sa` can connect via ODBC from other workstations on the domain (logged in as a domain user)
3. The SQL Server authentication is set for SQL Server and Windows authentication mode
4. The `sa` user does NOT have "Enforce password policy" checked
5. I have tried creating a new SQL admin user with the sysadmin role (same issue)
6. The SQL Server machine is a member of the samba4 domain

My environment:

**Database Server**

- SQL Server 2012 x64 Standard edition with service pack 3
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard x64

**Directory Server**

- CentOS 6.7 x64
- Samba 4.3

**smb.conf**

```
[global]

    workgroup = XYZ
    realm = XYZ.COM
    netbios name = DS01
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
    tls enabled  = yes
    tls keyfile  = tls/key.pem
    tls certfile = tls/cert.pem
    tls cafile   = tls/ca.pem
[netlogon]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/xyz.com/scripts
    read only = No
[sysvol]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol
    read only = No
[home]
    path = /home/
    comment = Home Directories
#   read only = No
    browseable = no
    writable = yes
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
```

Comment: I have read elsewhere that this is a known issue.  Evidently there is an incompatibility with Samba and the fact that it runs "Simple AD."  I found a workaround here: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/simple-ad/admin_troubleshooting.html#sql_login_fail)  it basiclly states to login as a local user and run SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment.  Although there seems to be no answer at this point other than wait for a fix.  The workaround is to login as a local user and run SQL Server Management Studio